# Identity element of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I already proved Closure and Associativity, now I'm trying to find the identity element of this operation defined as:
$$
a * b = a + b - ab
$$

But my identity element gets cancelled...

(The set defined in this exercise is the real numbers.)

[image]

Comment: The identity element is 0.

Comment: The specific mistake you made is that $e=ae$ doesn't _necessarily_ imply that $a=1$ - you have to recognize that that involves a division by $e$ and so you need to consider what happens if you divide by zero (in this case, you find the intended solution).

Comment: I think you're going to have a problem proving inverses exist.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki you are right, I didn't realize that.

Comment: Note:  this is not actually a group, as written, since $a * 1 = 1$ for all $a$ (equivalent to $a \cdot 0 = 0$ for all $a$ with usual multiplication).  If you want a group, then your underlying set needs to exclude the number one:  $G = (\Bbb{R} \setminus \{1\}, *)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:** The identity element in $(\mathbb{R},*)$ is the real number zero.

**Proof:** For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $x*0=x+0-x\times 0=x$. Since the identity element in a group is unique, zero is the identity element.

Following your way, suppose the identity is $e$, it has to satisfy that $a*e=a+e-a\times e=a$. This implies that $e=a\times e$. Suppose $e\ne 0$, then we would get $a=1$, which is impossible since we know that there are lots of real numbers that not equal to zero! So $e=0$.

Comment: Yes, in this case it's easy to see that 0 is the identity element. But using the equations I defined (so far thats how we did the excercises in class), is any way I can get e = 0 ? Instead of just replacing 0 in the definition

Comment: @Edu Please see the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @Edu Also I suppose it's more natural to proceed in your way. You just have to be careful when cancelling the $e$ because we don't know what it is, and it could be zero.

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answers, the identity element is $0$. If the goal was to prove or disprove that this is a group, you checked the axioms in an unfortunate order, because inverses don't exist. In particular, $1$ does not have an inverse, because $a\ast 1=1$ for all $a$.

Comment: Yes, we use to prove in this order: closure, associativity, indentity and inverse. I'll try to find the inverse by what you said, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation was good up to
$$
e = ae.
$$
Remember that if $e$ is to be the identity, then you want this equation to hold **for all $a$**.  If you like, you can rewrite the equation as
$$
0 = (a-1)e,
$$
The only solution is $e = 0$.

---

By the way, there's a neat way to understand this operation, using the function $r$, defined by $r(x) = 1 - x$.  The equation $c = a * b$ is equivalent to 
$$
\begin{align}
r(c) &= r(a) \cdot r(b) \\
(1-c) &= (1-a) (1-b) \\
1 - c &= 1 - a - b + ab \\
c &= a + b - ab
\end{align}
$$

Luckily $r$ is its own inverse:  $r(r(x)) = x$ for all $x$.  (It's a reflection about the point $x = \tfrac12$.)  So, all of the structure and properties of the *usual* multiplication on the reals is transferred over (and back) to the $*$ multiplication by $r$.

The multiplicative identity for usual multiplication is $1$, so the multiplicative identity for $*$ multiplication is
$$
r(1) = 1 - 1 = 0.
$$

In algebra, a map such as $r$ that acts as a dictionary, translating from one structure to an equivalent one, is called an *[isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism)*.